# Process JSON response single string

Tags: jquery, json

I have json that looks like this in php

```
json_encode('Test string');
```

it sends the string back i checked with firebug.
how can i access it?

```
 success: function(theResponse) {           

           alert()

    }
```

what should i put inside alert to get that string?

Answer (score 4):

You should format your output as valid JSON even if it's single string:

```
json_encode(array("message" => "No Return Email Address Specified!"));
```

Then you can access it in JS like this:

```
 success: function(theResponse) {           

       alert(theResponse.message)

}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't need to be a structure like an array or an object.  A single instance of a string is valid JSON.

Comment: Of course, but if it's dictionary there no doubts on how the string should be accessed :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use .$ on the response object

```
success: function(theResponse) {           
    alert(theResponse.$)  
}
```