# Parsing jsonarray in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

i need to parse the json array contacts from the below json

```
{

    },
    //Truncated for clarity
   ]
}
```

Comment: That's valid JSON according to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com), what's the problem?

Comment: What is the issue you are having parsing this?

Comment: i need to parse the jsonarray contacts

Comment: i get all the datas when parsing but in contacts array i need to get the "t" and "w" separately

Comment: i used the getString() but when "t"is not "w" is getting as "t" data

Comment: You will need to post your parsing code in order for us to understand what you mean, in addition if using a library to deserialize the json please provide that information as well.

Comment: this is how am parsing http://pastie.org/3766547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this isnt not a valid Json. normal Json must have a `"Label"` : `"value"`. Label and value must be seperated by colon `:`

```
"w","www.firmdale.com"
```

Should be like this

```
"w":"www.firmdale.com"
```

http://code.google.com/p/jsonvalidator/

Edited: to be more clear and specific as per **Aroth**

```
object
    {}
    { members } 
members
    pair
    pair , members
pair
    string : value
array
    []
    [ elements ]
elements
    value
    value , elements
value
    string
    number
    object
    array
    true
    false
    null
```

Comment: It's valid JSON, but *logically* they should have used a JSON *object* instead of a JSON *array* for storing the individual contact entries.

Comment: You should format your output as valid JSON even if it's single string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950297/process-json-response-single-string see link's comment specially.

Comment: ya read it... can i der be any solution or is it needed to change in webservice

Comment: and also refer http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?22990-Json-Invalid-label

Answer (score 4):

Parsing is easy.  First get [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and add it to your project (or you can use the built-in JSON library, if you like how everything in that library can throw a checked `JSONException`).

Next, your entire response-text is a valid JSON object.  So do:

```
JSONObject response = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(responseText);
```

Your object has an array of results under the "result" key.  You can get that like:

```
JSONArray results = (JSONArray)response.get("result");
```

Your array contains a set of objects that you want to iterate over to get the contact info for each one.  For example:

```
for (Object obj : results) {
    JSONObject entry = (JSONObject)obj;
    JSONArray contacts = (JSONArray)entry.get("contact");
    for (Object contact : contacts) {
        System.out.println(contact);
    }
}
```

Note that whomever put that JSON together decided to use an array type for holding each individual contact entry.  An object type would have made a lot more sense, but as-is, `contact.get(0)` will give you the type-code for the contact entry (`t`, `w`, etc.), and `contact.get(1)` will give you the actual contact number/address/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private JSONObject jObject;
 jObject = new JSONObject(your response as string);
 //this will give you json object for HotelInformationResponse
 JSONArray menuitemArray = popupObject.getJSONArray("result"); 
 // loop through this array to get all values
```

for extra information [Check this link](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/)